# why rails docs says to put inverse_of on a belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Why [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations) says to use `inverse_of` in `has_* - belongs_to` relations?

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, inverse_of: :customer
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :orders
end
```

<strike>Anyway while playing with rails i can see it's raising an error when you put `inverse_of` in `belongs_to` association. Are my observations correct (and the docs are missing the point) or am I doing something wrong?</strike>

It turns out to be my typo + an IDE magic thing that made me thinking it was rails thing.

Comment: what error you are getting? Please post it on your question

Comment: @shivam I've updated the question to provide info about the error.

Comment: post the error as it is. (copy paste the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why rails docs says to put inverse_of on a belongs_to relation

This is done for memory optimization when fetching associated records. Associated objects do not point to the same in-memory objects by default. Therefore whenever you'll do `order.customer` without `inverse_of` on both the `:belongs_to` and `:has_many` associations, it will hit the database. With `:inverse_of`, if we already have that customer record in memory then `order.customer` will point to the same customer.

For detailed reference: http://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations

Comment: sorry for late response. Anyway it was my mistake so i've edited the question, but your answer is still relevant, so i'm accepting. Thanks for help!